# How to run KSQLDB along with Kafka server using docker compose

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, ksqldb

I'm trying to run KSQLDB along with Kafka, but KSQLDB refuses to connect to my Kafka Server.

```
kafka1-kafka-1   | [2024-02-19 17:08:15,202] INFO [BrokerLifecycleManager id=1] Unable to register broker 1 because the controller returned error DUPLICATE_BROKER_REGISTRATION (kafka.server.BrokerLifecycleManager)
kafka1-ksqldb-1  | [2024-02-19 17:08:16,320] INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
kafka1-ksqldb-1  | [2024-02-19 17:08:16,321] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (kafka/172.18.0.2:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
kafka1-kafka-1   | [2024-02-19 17:08:16,809] INFO [QuorumController id=1] registerBroker: failed with DuplicateBrokerRegistrationException in 293 us. Reason: Another broker is registered with that broker id. (org.apache.kafka.controller.QuorumController)
kafka1-kafka-1   | [2024-02-19 17:08:16,813] INFO [BrokerLifecycleManager id=1] Unable to register broker 1 because the controller returned error DUPLICATE_BROKER_REGISTRATION (kafka.server.BrokerLifecycleManager)
```

My docker-compose.yaml looks like this:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/confluent-local:latest
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "8082:8082"
      - "29093:29093"
  ksqldb:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:7.5.3
    environment:
      - KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092
      - KSQL_KSQL_SERVICE_ID=ksqldb_
      - KSQL_KSQL_QUERIES_FILE=/opt/data/queries.sql
      - KSQL_LISTENERS=http://0.0.0.0:8088/
    depends_on:
      - kafka
```

What I need is basically a docker-compose file that can run the two images and let me experiment with tables and streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing some environment variables on the Kafka container

```
KAFKA_LISTENERS: "PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:29092,CONTROLLER://kafka:29093,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9092" 
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092"
```

It defaults to localhost, so no other containers can connect

And you need `KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:29092` on ksql (change the port)

Comment: Thanks. It solved one of the problems with Kafka it self.
Unfortunately, KSQLDB still cannot connect:
kafka1-ksqldb-1  | [2024-02-19 18:43:37,421] INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
kafka1-ksqldb-1  | [2024-02-19 18:43:37,422] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (kafka/172.22.0.2:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

Comment: Updated answer. You can find defaults here https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-images/blob/7.4.x/local/include/etc/confluent/docker/configureDefaults#L24

Comment: KSQLDB: "Broker not available". KAFKA: "Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:29093) could not be established. Broker may not be available".
Would appreciate a working sample of a docker-compose file

Comment: Ksql doesn't need to connect to port 29093. That's the rest proxy. Confluent already has docker compose examples https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/7.5.0-post/cp-all-in-one-kraft/docker-compose.yml#L101

Comment: Ok, using the docker compose example as pointed out and changed the Kafka image to confluent-local and omitted various settings, I got it to work. Thanks @OneCricketeer